# jquery mobile checkboxes

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Here are my jquery mobile checkboxes[image]

i want to change its background color. i am using this piece of code

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" style = "width:200px; padding-    
top:7px;">
<input name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox5" style = "color:#0A6E9A;" >
My Choice 1
</label>
<input name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox6" style = "color:#0A6E9A; background-
color:#AFDCEF;" >
My Choice 2
</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change background color by adding your style "**color:#0A6E9A; background-color:#AFDCEF;**" in "**.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-inner**" in your "**jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css**" file. 
see the output of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sV3D2/

Answer (score 0):

Alternately I recommend creating a new theme style for these specific type of buttons. If you make the change stated above you will effect all buttons across the board.   I usually do "data-theme=""  and then I can create a new theme for these specific buttons.